# Report Background Thread Progress on UI Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'd like to achieve following result - UI thread registers the progress changed event of my time consuming operation and then runs the method "DoOperationAsync()". The operation will then report back a progress change, but: **The event has to be invoked on the UI thread**, which I am having problem achieving. The event fires, but when I try to update UI, I need to use Dispatcher, because the event is fired from the thread doing the operation. I don't feel like my library should force the developer to think ahead and use dispatchers everywhere.

Basically I'd like to do what BackgroundWorker does. **How does BackgroundWorker fire an ProgressChanged event on the thread that created it?**

Comment: No you don't need to use Dispatcher with backgroundworker reportsprgress.  Follow the sample on MSDN.

Comment: Read the question again - I am not using BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Why not use BackgroundWorker?

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` uses the `AsyncOperation.Post` method to invoke the event on the appropriate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `BackgroundWorker` uses the [`Event-based asynchronous pattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx).

Internally, it uses an instance of [`class AsyncOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.aspx) to raise the event.

Specifically, it calls [`AsyncOperation.Post()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.post.aspx) to raise the event on the appropriate thread or context.

You should be able to do that with your library code.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I am looking into. My code is as follows:

http://pastebin.com/0SrWRvnj

But the UI thread still reports error about another thread owning the control.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to have the background thread change the progress bar (or whatever you're using to track progress). This is not allowed. You can do one of two things: from the background thread, periodically trigger an event on your UI that posts progress data and then the UI renders the progress; 2) use `Invoke` to invoke a method or property on a UI control from the background thread in order to update progress. You cannot access UI element methods or properties directly from background threads.

Comment: @OndraMašitů Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hk12d4y.aspx It gives you more info on how to initialise the AsyncOperation class so that it works correctly. You need to use [`AsyncOperationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the AsyncOperation. Unfortunately, this stuff is quite fiddly.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight That is of course true. Please read carefully my question.

Comment: To summarize: `BackgroundWorker` uses `AsyncOperation` which uses `SynchronizationContext` which (in this case) uses `Dispatcher`. While you *could* write an [EAP component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) using `AsyncOperation` or `SynchronizationContext`, I'd recommend you write a [TAP component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) instead; task-based APIs are the future of asynchronous programming. BTW, `Progress<T>` also uses `SynchronizationContext` which (in this case) uses `Dispatcher`. :)

Comment: Thank you guys, this thread I am marking as an answer. While I wasn't able to figure out how to make it work so it reports the progress on UI thread (it does report, but on it's own separate thread), the BackgroundWorker sure does the job and works the same way.

Also, I am stuck on 4.0 as the app needs to run on Windows XP, too.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using .NET 4.5, you'll have access to the latest version of TPL changes, which includes the [`IProgress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298.aspx) interface and its concrete implementation [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx). The interface was designed to support progress reporting between two asynchronous tasks, specifically the background-to-UI-thread reporting you're after.

The interface itself is simple, defining the [`Report(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193864.aspx) method as the mechanism for passing a progress update of type `T` to the other task. When you have some progress to report, you invoke the operation. If you wanted to pass a percentage progress, you could pass `0.1` to an `IProgress<float>` instance to report 10% progress.

```
private async Task BackgroundWorkAsync(IProgress<float> progress)
{
    ...

    progress.Report(0.1); // 10%

    ...

    progress.Report(1.0); // 100%
}
```

The UI thread is expected to create the concrete `Progress<T>` instance and pass it into the scope of the background task. `Progress<T>` provides a [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137516.aspx) event you can subscribe to, but normally you pass an action to the constructor to be called each time progress is updated:

```
var progress = new Progress(value => // set progress bar);

await this.BackgroundWorkAsync(progress);
```

This is a crude example, but it shows the magic of how `Progress<T>` synchronizes the callback according to the context, which in this case would be the UI thread.

Comment: That does sound great and I will give it a try on some of my future projects, but the app I am currently working on has to run on Windows XP, too. So I am stuck with 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a while ago, and don't have the code to remember exactly how I did it, but here is the basis of what I did.  In my UI object where I created my background worker, I also created a method that gets triggered when progress is reported.  Then, in the background worker, I set public properties that I could read from and put into my UI.

```
public class myUIFormControlWhatever
{
   ...
   public void CallTheBackgroundWorker()
   {
      myBackgroundWorker bgw = new myBackgroundWorker();
      // attach "listening" when the background worker reports changes
      bgw.ProgressChanged += thisObjectShowChangedProgress;
      bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
   }

   protected void thisObjectShowChangedProgress( object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e )
   {
      this.SomeTextShownOnUI = ((myBackgroundWorker)sender).ExposedProperty;
   }
}


public class myBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
   public myBackgroundWorker()
   {
      WorkerReportsProgress = true;
      // hook up internal to background worker any strings
      // you want to expose once reporting and any other listeners are out there.
      ProgressChanged += StatusUpdate;
   }

   protected void StatusUpdate( object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e )
   {
      // set property to what you want any other listeners to grab/display
      ExposedProperty = "something you are handling internally to background worker";
   }

   public string ExposedProperty
   { get; protected set; }

}
```

Again, most of this is from memory with lookup of event handler parameter arguments I couldn't remember signature of.   So the UI creates the background worker but listens to any reported changes by hooking up to the "ProgressChanged" event.  So once the background worker does it's thing, the UI component handles it's own segment by looking at properties that would be visible to read from the "object sender" parameter which is the background worker itself.

Comment: Thank you, that would indeed work, but I am looking into how background worker does it, that it is able to fire the event on a thread that originally called it's RunWorkerAsync method. See my answer at Matthew's comment. I believe he is right, it is just that I can't make the Post method work properly. It keeps calling it at wrong thread.

Comment: @OndraMašitů, I understand your issue, but I was just throwing the principle of what I had in the past.  When the background worker call all "listeners" to the event, the UI thread object now gets its own control and can operate on itself but just pulling a value from the background worker to be displayed.  Just another avenue of thinking that might also help in your final solution.